# .htaccess IF directory exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a development server and a live server. Both use the same .htaccess but I want the development server to be password protected. When I copy the .htaccess file over to the live, I get a 500 error. Does .htaccess offer some way to only password protect directories using conditionals like IF?

what I'm using:

```
<Directory "/home/my/path/to/development/site/">
  AuthName "Restricted Area 52" 
  AuthType Basic 
  AuthUserFile /home/my/path/to/development/site/.htpasswd 
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
  require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Could really use some help.

Comment: Yes, it is since it's a direct copy of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `<Directory>` containers inside an htaccess file, but you can conditionally turn on or off HTTP auth based on an environment varaible.

So for example, say your production site is `http://production.example.com` and your dev site is `http://dev.example.com` then you can check against the HTTP Host and set an environment variable:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^dev\.example\.com$ require_auth=true
```

Or, if the path is different, say your production site is `http://example.com/` and dev site is `http://example.com/dev/`, then you can check against the requested URI:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/dev/ require_auth=true
```

There's several other checks you can make that's outlined in the [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html). Either way, you want to set `require_auth=true` when it's a request for dev. Then you setup your auth stuff to use `Satisfy Any`:

```
# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /home/my/path/to/development/site/.htpasswd 
AuthName "Restricted Area 52"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

So if `require_auth` isn't set, then no auth is required, and your `SetenvIf` should set it if it's a dev request.